# Is there any way to put multiple CSS style rules at different location in a file at one place in CSS?

Tags: css

What I am trying to say is that I am working on a project where styles have been added randomly wherever the developer wanted. It is a mess to work with. For example,

```
p {
  color: brown;
}

.... somewhere else in the same stylesheet

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.... somewhere else in the same stylesheet

a , p {
  line-height: 1.7;
}
```

What I would like to do is combine styles that use same selector like this:

```
p {
  color: brown;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

a {
  line-height: 1.7;
}
```

**I am not asking if merging styles like this will work or not. I am asking if there is any automated solution that can do the merging. It will be a nightmare to go through 100kb of text to look for selectors.**

Comment: that should work

Comment: Yes, just merge them all together and it'll work fine.

Comment: Are you looking for an automated solution? Or asking if your second example is correct?

Comment: @Turnip I am asking for an automated solution.

Comment: I don't think there is an automated solution. Depending on the code editor you are using the quickest could be to `Ctrl+F` for the `tag, class, or id` you want to merge` your code editor should highlight it and then you can pick and merge.

Comment: @OkeTega Thanks but it will still take a lot of time. :)

Comment: Your question made me research and i think you should read https://www.sitepoint.com/terrific-time-saving-css-tools/

Comment: You should try http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Comment: Thanks @shubhamagrawal :)

Comment: Probably downvote is due to your irrelevant tag: `html`.